# Is there a way to run a javascript function without making a request in the network tab?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

Okay it will sound dumb but this is my third week in javascript and i am still trying to learn. So i am trying to build a project (scraping tool) That scraps website B. But when i try to call function from my html it gives me NO-CORS or FORBIDDEN ERROR 403. After some googling i figured out that website B is just blocking me but whenever i run the js file on vscode alone without running it from the index.html it works perfectly and it actually scraps the data

Tried using few cors proxies which solved the NO-CORS part but i can't figure out why when i run my js file in vscode the it actually scraps website B but when i try to use it when i make my website live it gives me a 403 ERROR.

Comment: there's a difference between code running on a server vs in a browser - server code has no CORS limitation when *borrowing* other peoples resources from another server - browsers have such limitations baked in for security and other reasons

Comment: This is why you can't scrape form a browser. All browsers will block you from trying to request from a different domain (website) unless that website explicitely **allow** you  to do it using the CORS mechanism (the website don't have to block you, browsers block by default). You need to scrape from a computer (not a browser running on a computer). The upside is that since you must scrape outside of browsers you can use any programming language you want to do the scraping.

Comment: If the website you are trying to scrape require javascript to run to show content then there are libraries out there like Selenium that allow you to control browsers from your own code (Selenium is available in many languages)

Comment: @slebetman so it is not possible to scrape data and show the scraped data on my website? But i can use it on my machine only right?

Comment: Most people would run their websites on a server. If you're just using a web hosting service that doesn't let you run your own programs you can rent a linux machine and have full control. Linode's cheapest tier is around $5 a month. I think AWS will still give you 1 year free if you open an account.

Comment: Another alternative is to go old-school. Don't develop a website, instead develop a desktop app and let people download your app if they want to use it.

Comment: @slebetman i was thinking maybe run js on my machine and make it write to an excel sheet and make the html file read from that excel sheet. But that desktop app idea is lowkey a lot better thanks mate appreciate your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The other server isn't blocking you at least not per se.

When your browser tried to get resources from the other server it does a preflight connection that says "hey I came here from xyz site, are you ok with that?". The other server checks to see if xyz is on its list of acceptable origins (aka referrers) and sees that it isn't and that's when you get the 403.

When you're in a non-browser environment then your fetch just says "hey I didn't come here from anywhere" so there's no referrer list to check. That's why it works in vsc.

Modern browsers are hard coded not to let some random js code to skip that check so there's nothing you can do in code.